# What is the bootTel.dat file in Windows?

Tags: windows-10

I noticed this file at `C:\bootTel.dat` on Windows 10. It is a very small file. The owner is Administrators and Everyone has Full Control.

Answer (score 13):

This file appears to be related to [autochk.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/autochk), which is sometimes run by Windows at startup to check for filesystem issues. You can confirm this by running the command-line SysInternals [strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) tool on `C:\Windows\System32\autochk.exe` and you'll see the string `bootTel.dat`, with its distinctive capitalization.

If you check the modified date of `C:\bootTel.dat`, you may notice that it is near the time of an Event Log event like the following:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Wininit
Event ID: 1001
Description starting with "Checking file system"
```

Based on the name, my guess is that the file is telemetry information written by `autochk.exe` and read by Windows later to tell Microsoft about filesystem issues, so that they may improve Windows in the future.